# Can you translate these sentences in english please? Is it correct to say it? Which one is better (polite and natural)?

Tags: translation

Hello everyone I have a question could you help me?
Which of the following sentences sounds more natural and polite?

플랫폼 끝까지 걸어니다
Or
플랫폼 끝까지 걸어주세요

Comment: Hi Patneil, welcome to the site. Neither of these sentences seems like natural Korean - did you see these somewhere, or is it that you want to translate something into Korean?

Comment: The first one doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

**플랫폼 끝까지 걸어 다니다**

He ambulates on the whole platform, except a fixed spot.

@ 걸어 = walk

다니다 = move by replacing a body.

어니 다녀 오세요 ? = 어디 갔다 오세요 ? = Where did you go before here ?

어디 다니니 ? = where do you go ? (place) where do you attend ? (job or participation) : In situation, we can pick a suitable meaning.

**플랫폼 끝까지 걸어 주세요.**

Please, stop at the end of platform

= Please, walk to the end of platform

@ 주세요 = please, you would give me.